# Is it slower to read files from another partition?

Tags: partitioning, files, filesystem, io

Lets say there is a set of binary files in partition A. I copy them to partition B. I run a program that runs in partition A. Would it be slower for the program to read the files in partition B than the ones in parititon A?

Related question: What about writing to files that are in another partition? Would it be slower to write to files that are located in another partition than to files that are in the same partition as the program that is writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A computer will read and write to a partition as fast as the data bus will allow. Partitions on the same device will move at the same speed. Partitions on different devices will move at the maximum speed the storage medium can handle.

| Medium | Opinion |
| --- | --- |
| NVMe | Reasonably fast |
| SSD | Acceptably fast |
| HDD | Workable if needs be |
| USB-connected | Tolerable on occasion, decent for backups |
| SD/eMMC | Oh my goodness ... hurry up, please |

Hope this answers your question